# adb install error OBB file unreal Andriod aar

Tags: java, xml, adb

adb: failed to install Sppechtest-Android-DebugGame-armv7.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl255244500.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #59): com.epicgames.ue4.SplashActivity: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]

There was an error installing the game or the obb file. Look above for more info.

I have only one XML

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--ARToolKit plugin additions-->
<root xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!-- init section is always evaluated once per architecture -->
  <init>
    <log text="Speech Recognition init"/>
  </init>

  <androidManifestUpdates>
    <addPermission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_USERS"/>
    <addPermission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <addPermission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <addPermission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
  </androidManifestUpdates>

  <!-- optional files or directories to copy to Intermediate/Android/APK -->
  
  
  `<resourceCopies>
    <copyFile src="$S(ProjectDir)/Plugins/SpeechRecognition/Android/libs/pocketsphinx-android-5prealpha-nolib.jar"
                        dst="$S(BuildDir)/libs/pocketsphinx-android-5prealpha-nolib.jar" />
    <copyFile src="$S(ProjectDir)/Plugins/SpeechRecognition/Android/jni/armeabi-v7a/libpocketsphinx_jni.so"
        dst="$S(BuildDir)/libs/libpocketsphinx_jni.so" />
  </resourceCopies>`
    
    
    <AARImports>
        <insertValue value="Libs/pocketsphinx-android-5prealpha-release.aar" />
        <insertNewline/>
    </AARImports>
    
    
  <gameActivityImportAdditions>
    <insert>
      import android.widget.Toast;
      import android.hardware.Camera;
      import android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo;
      import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
      import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
      import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
      import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
      import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
      import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
      import java.io.IOException;
      import java.io.File;
      import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
      import java.io.FileInputStream;
      import java.io.FileOutputStream;
      import java.util.Map;
      import java.util.HashMap;
      import java.util.HashSet;
      import java.util.ArrayList;
      import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;
      import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
      import java.util.List;
      import android.util.Log;
      import com.android.vending.expansion.zipfile.ZipResourceFile;
      import com.android.vending.expansion.zipfile.ZipResourceFile.ZipEntryRO;
      import com.android.vending.expansion.zipfile.APKExpansionSupport;
      import com.sphinxue4.SpeechRecognitionWorker;
    </insert>
  </gameActivityImportAdditions>

  <gameActivityClassAdditions>
    <insert>


      private static SpeechRecognitionWorker worker;
      private static Thread workerThread;
      private static File obbDir;

      public static void unzip(File zipFile, File targetDirectory) throws IOException {
      ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(
      new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile)));
      try {

      ZipEntry ze;
      int count;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
      while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
      File file = new File(targetDirectory, ze.getName());

      Log.debug("Unzip: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

      // only extract if path contains "model"
      if(!file.getAbsolutePath().contains("model")) {
      Log.debug("File irrelevant, skipping : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
      continue;
      }

      if(file.exists()) {
      Log.debug("File exists, skipping : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
      continue;
      }
      File dir = ze.isDirectory() ? file : file.getParentFile();
      if (!dir.isDirectory() &amp;&amp; !dir.mkdirs())
      throw new FileNotFoundException("Failed to ensure directory: " +
      dir.getAbsolutePath());
      if (ze.isDirectory())
      continue;
      FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
      try {
      while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1)
      fout.write(buffer, 0, count);
      } finally {
      fout.close();
      }
      }
      } finally {
      zis.close();
      }
      }

      private void extractOBB() {
      try{
      String expansionFilePath = "/storage/emulated/0/obb/"+getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/main.1."+ getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".obb";
      Log.debug("ExtractOBB: " +expansionFilePath);
      ZipResourceFile apkExpansionFile = new ZipResourceFile(expansionFilePath);
      if(apkExpansionFile != null)
      {
      ZipEntryRO[] entries = apkExpansionFile.getAllEntries();
      Log.debug("Expansion File Counter: " + entries.length);
      HashSet&lt;File&gt; extractFiles = new HashSet&lt;File&gt;();
      for(ZipEntryRO entry : entries) {
      File f = entry.getZipFile();
      extractFiles.add(f);
      }

      for(File zipFile : extractFiles) {
      String path = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
      File dest = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
      unzip(zipFile, dest);
      }
      }

      }catch(Exception e) {
      Log.debug("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
      }
      }

      // create the speech recognition worker
      public void AndroidThunkJava_CreateSpeechRecognition() {
      try {
      Log.debug("Start AndroidThunkJava_CreateSpeechRecognition");
      worker = new SpeechRecognitionWorker();
      worker.init();
      workerThread = new Thread(worker);
      workerThread.setDaemon(true);
      workerThread.start();
      workerThread.join();
      Log.debug("End AndroidThunkJava_CreateSpeechRecognition");
      }catch (Exception e) {
      Log.debug("AndroidThunkJava_CreateSpeechRecognition failed with exception " + e.getMessage());
      }
      }

      // Destroy the speech recognition worker
      public void AndroidThunkJava_ShutdownSpeechRecognition() {
      try {
      Log.debug("Start AndroidThunkJava_ShutdownSpeechRecognition");
      worker.stopListening();
      Log.debug("End AndroidThunkJava_ShutdownSpeechRecognition");
      }catch (Exception e) {
      Log.debug("AndroidThunkJava_ShutdownSpeechRecognition failed with exception " + e.getMessage());
      }
      }

      //  init the speech recognition worker
      public void AndroidThunkJava_SetKeywordPhrases(final String[] phrases, final String[] tollerence, final int keyCount) {
      Thread thread = new Thread() {
      public void run() {
      try {
      Log.debug("Start AndroidThunkJava_SetKeywordPhrases");
      Log.debug("Stop Listening");
      worker.stopListening();
      Log.debug("Stopped Listening");
      worker.init();
      worker.setKeywordPhrases(phrases, tollerence, keyCount);
      workerThread = new Thread(worker);
      workerThread.setDaemon(true);
      workerThread.start();
      Log.debug("End AndroidThunkJava_SetKeywordPhrases");
      }catch (Exception e) {
      Log.debug("AndroidThunkJava_SetKeywordPhrases failed with exception " + e.getMessage());
      }
      }
      };
      thread.start();
      }

      public void AndroidThunkJava_SetGrammarMode(final String grammarName) {
      Thread thread = new Thread() {
      public void run() {
      try {
      Log.debug("Start AndroidThunkJava_SetGrammarMode");
      Log.debug("Stop Listening");
      worker.stopListening();
      Log.debug("Stopped Listening");
      worker.init();
      worker.setGrammarMode(grammarName);
      workerThread = new Thread(worker);
      workerThread.setDaemon(true);
      workerThread.start();
      Log.debug("End AndroidThunkJava_SetGrammarMode");
      }catch (Exception e) {
      Log.debug("AndroidThunkJava_SetGrammarMode failed with exception " + e.getMessage());
      }
      }
      };
      thread.start();
      }

      public void AndroidThunkJava_SetLanguageModel(final String langName) {
      Thread thread = new Thread() {
      public void run() {
      try {
      Log.debug("Start AndroidThunkJava_SetLanguageModel");
      Log.debug("Stop Listening");
      worker.stopListening();
      Log.debug("Stopped Listening");
      worker.init();
      worker.setLanguageModel(langName);
      workerThread = new Thread(worker);
      workerThread.setDaemon(true);
      workerThread.start();
      Log.debug("End AndroidThunkJava_SetLanguageModel");
      }catch (Exception e) {
      Log.debug("AndroidThunkJava_SetLanguageModel failed with exception " + e.getMessage());
      }
      }
      };
      thread.start();
      }


      // logs text - test
      public boolean AndroidThunkJava_LogTxt(String txt) {
      try {
      Log.debug("Start AndroidThunkJava_LogTxt");
      worker.LogTxt(txt);
      Log.debug("End AndroidThunkJava_LogTxt");
      return true;
      }catch (Exception e) {
      Log.debug("AndroidThunkJava_LogTxt failed with exception " + e.getMessage());
      return false;
      }
      }


    </insert>
  </gameActivityClassAdditions>

  <!-- optional additions to GameActivity onCreate in GameActivity.java -->
 <gameActivityOnCreateAdditions>
    <insert>
      extractOBB();
    </insert>
  </gameActivityOnCreateAdditions>


</root>`
```

Comment: You should look at the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in the APK file, to see what Android is complaining about. In your project there should also be such a file. BTW: Are you sure you selected the correct architecture? armv7 belongs to very old devices, it is still supported but for a game I would recommend to use the ARMv8/arm64 version.

Comment: If I change the arm . I get the following errors. 

UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Z:\app\src\main\java\com\sphinxue4\SpeechRecognitionWorker.java:45: error: SpeechRecognitionWorker is not abstract and does not override abstract method onResult(Hypothesis) in RecognitionListener
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): public class SpeechRecognitionWorker implements Runnable, RecognitionListener {
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):        ^
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Z:\app\src\main\java\com\sphinxue4\SpeechRecognitionWorker.java:108: error: cannot find symbol

Comment: How to i change settings in unreal so that it merge the AndroidManifest.xml with android:exported true? i see that in intermediate it has false.